# Can you write in dynamodb at the same time from parallel or asynchronous functions while being in a free layer?

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

execution without parallel functions: time = x

execution with 4 parallel functions: time = x / 4

When the code attached with 4 parallel functions is executed, the total time is not divided for 4, but is maintained.

my question is:
Does Dynamodb support parallel function table writes?

```py
def patronfanin_out(event, context):
    for i in range(4):
        x= list #aqui envio una lista nueva para cada función
        response = lambda_client.invoke(
        FunctionName="tesis-aws-patrones-dev-workers",
        InvocationType='Event',
        Payload=json.dumps(x)
      )

def workers(event, context):
  table = boto3.resource('dynamodb').Table('patron2')
  rowsFinal = event['list']
  for row in rowsFinal:
    table.put_item(Item={
        'id': str(uuid.uuid4()),
        'serie': row[0],
        'rank': row[1],
        'discipline': row[2],
        'sex': row[3],
        'salary': row[4]
        })
  response = {
      "statusCode": 200,
      "params" : rowsFinal
  }
  return response
```

I wish that the total execution time of the function will decrease considerably, since I am using 4 parallel functions.
total execution time: x
total execution time wish: x/4

Answer (score 0):

```
  for row in rowsFinal:
    table.put_item(Item={
        'id': str(uuid.uuid4()),
        'serie': row[0],
        'rank': row[1],
        'discipline': row[2],
        'sex': row[3],
        'salary': row[4]
        })
```

This doesn't seem to run in parallel, but in an iterative way

**EDIT**

**invoke**, as stated in https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke is synchronous, it waits for the response.

Use **invoke_async** https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke_async and they will run in parallel.

**EDIT 2**

Instead of `table.put_item` use `batch_write_item()`

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.batch_write_item

And group them by max 25 items or 16MB total https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html

Comment: Is there any configuration for dynamo to support writes in parallel?

Comment: Dynamodb supports parallel writes, but in your case Lambda is the issue, as it waits for the write operation to finish.

Comment: `def patronfanin_out(event, context):
    for i in range(4):
        x= list #aqui envio una lista nueva para cada función
        response = lambda_client.invoke_async(
        FunctionName="tesis-aws-patrones-dev-workers",
        InvokeArgs=json.dumps(x)
      )` I have used the following code as you suggest without improving the results.

Comment: how many items are there to put in each one of those 4 calls? (`list` or `rowsFinal` expected size)

Comment: A list of 25,000 elements divided into 6250 for each parallel function.

Comment: I send a csv through a form (method = Post).

Comment: I would suggest then to store the csv in S3 and use Data Pipelines. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-importexport-ddb-part1.html and https://hackernoon.com/performance-increase-of-data-pipelines-from-s3-to-dynamodb-jl8g3xiq

Comment: also this https://hackernoon.com/build-a-serverless-data-pipeline-with-aws-s3-lamba-and-dynamodb-5ecb8c3ed23e

Comment: What happens is that my thesis is to apply the fan-out pattern and pipes and filters (Data Pipelines), so the approach that I suggest should also be implemented later.

Comment: yes, data pipeline would work much better than put commands in your case

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback and time. I will use both approaches, you have some practical example of parallel functions against dynamo, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Can you write in dynamodb at the same time from parallel or asynchronous functions while being in a free layer?